# Cookies on Windows Phone 8.1 using HttpClient

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using the `HttpClient` in `theSystem.Net.Http` but I'm having problems dealing with cookies. I have come through other posts explaining how to setup up cookies with `HttpClient.` I create a `CookieContainer` for the `HttpClientHandler.CookieHandler` and use this container for the cookies. When initialized, its value is obviously 0 and after making the `PostAsync`, the `CookieContainer` contains one cookie. I run through a `foreach` loop to print the values and I get the value of the one cookie. This all seems like it's working as it should.

**The problem is** that even though it seems as I'm accepting cookies the website redirects me to a page informing me that I do not accept cookies. I have checked with a browser(making it not accept cookies) and it's the exact result i get with my `HttpClient`.

The overall function of my code is giving values for a login and try to post these. The login seems to be working as expected though it redirects me telling me I don't accept cookies - even though my `CookieContainer` does contain a cookie. I'm not sure where this goes wrong but it seems like the website can't see that I'm actually accepting cookies. I have tried setting `httpClientHandler.UseCookies = true;` but without any difference.  The website I'm trying to access is my university's system for reading grades and I do not have access to any coding of it.

My code is shown below:

```
{
  var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();


  //Creating cookiecontainer and printing Count for debug purpose
  var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  Debug.WriteLine("Cookies " + cookieContainer.Count);

  httpClientHandler.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

  var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

  Debug.WriteLine("Response code" + response.StatusCode);
  Debug.WriteLine("Response: " + response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

  string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  //Print amount of cookies after PostAsync - Should contain cookie now
  Debug.WriteLine("Cookies " + cookieContainer.Count);

 //Printing the values of the added cookies
  foreach (Cookie cookie in cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri(url)))
  {
      Debug.WriteLine("Cookie contains: " + cookie.Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

This is my first Windows Phone App and it is my first time using the `HttpClient` but I have used a few days now reading about it so hope the answer is not to obvious. Thank you very much - your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by tracking the the website with chrome. I realized that the *login page* was giving me 2 cookies when i first went to the page and 1 cookie when i logged in. The scenario can be described like this

- Get loginPage - 2 cookies
- Post LoginPage - 1 cookie

The problem was that I started out by doing a `httpClient.PostAsync` for the login. When doing the login i was missing the first 2 cookies.

I solved it by doing a httpClient.GetAsync before the post, I then got the totalt 3 cookies that was needed.

```
HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await httpClient.GetAsync(User.School.Url);
HttpResponseMessage responsePost = await httpClient.PostAsync(User.School.Url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));
```

The problem was probably caused by my lack of knowledge about cookies. If the website response is saying your are missing cookies then you probably are, be sure you tracked ALL the traffic correctly. Hope this can be helpful to someone else :)